# Slim Framework 3 - using router in a global template

Tags: php, slim

I'm relatively new to Slim Framework 3. One thing I'm trying to understand is how to use the router, `$this->router`, in a "global" template.

What I mean by this is a template such as a navigation menu - something that appears on every page.

For templates I'm using the "php-view" library as per the [example tutorial](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html) which I installed with:

`composer require slim/php-view`

In my templates directory I have a file called `nav.php` where I want to output my links.

I understand how to call the router like so

```
<a href="<?=$router->pathFor('sign-up')?>">Sign Up</a>
```

But... the example tutorial only shows how you would pass that link from 1 individual place, e.g. `$app->get('/sign-up' ... })->setName("sign-up");`

How can you use the router globally in any template, without passing it into every individual URL route as a parameter?

*I'm more familiar with frameworks like CakePHP where there is an "AppController" which allows you to set things globally, i.e. available in every request. I don't know if this is how it's done in Slim but this is the effect I'm after.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can pass it as [template variable](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#template-variables).

When you instantiate or register `PhpRenderer` in a container, you have multiple options to define a "global" variable, i.e. a variable that is accessible in  all of your templates:

```
// via the constructor
$templateVariables = [
    "router" => "Title"
];
$phpView = new PhpRenderer("./path/to/templates", $templateVariables);

// or setter
$phpView->setAttributes($templateVariables);

// or individually
$phpView->addAttribute($key, $value);
```

Assuming you're registering `PhpRenderer` via Pimple:

```
<?php
// Create application instance
$app = new \Slim\App();

// Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();

// Register PhpRenderer in the container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {

    // Declaring "global" variables
    $templateVariables = [
        'router' => $container->get('router')
    ];

    // And passing the array as second argument to the contructor
    return new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer('path/to/templates/with/trailing/slash/', $templateVariables);
};
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it. If you setup the Renderer in a container factory you can grab the instance of the router from the container and pass it into the Renderer as a template variable

Comment: @geggleto The trouble with this is that it passes the entire router object into every template. If I do `var_dump($router);` in my templates there's a huge array, which contains things I don't need - including DB credentials. Not sure if there's a more efficient way to do this where you can just get access to the named routes?

Comment: Since objects are passed by reference by default, there is no performance penalty in this solution. If you have a lot of non-primitive templates, consider using [the Slim Twig-view component](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View): this uses Twig library, which is far more powerful than 150 lines single-class `PhpRenderer`.

Comment: As the author of PhpRenderer, I approve of the above message ;) The PhpRenderer was a short-cut to get people into using Templates. If you have hit this stage of development Twig templates make way more sense... Although I will be building more features into PHP-View over the next few months

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers;

/********************/
//LinksHelper.php
/********************/

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class LinksHelper
{  
    protected $ci;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container){
      $this->ci = $container;
    }

    public function __get($property){
        if ($this->ci->has($property)) {
          return $this->ci->get($property);
        }
    }

    public function pathFor($name, $data = [], $queryParams = [], $appName = 'default')
    {
        return $this->router->pathFor($name, $data, $queryParams);
    }

    public function baseUrl()
    {
        if (is_string($this->uri)) {
            return $this->uri;
        }
        if (method_exists($this->uri, 'getBaseUrl')) {
            return $this->uri->getBaseUrl();
        }
    }

    public function isCurrentPath($name, $data = [])
    {
        return $this->router->pathFor($name, $data) === $this->uri->getPath();
    }

    public function setBaseUrl($baseUrl)
    {
        $this->uri = $baseUrl;
    }
}

?>

<?php
/********************/
//dependencies.php
/********************/

$container['link'] = function ($c) {
  return new \App\Helpers\LinksHelper($c);
};

// view renderer
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings');
    $view = new App\Views\MyPhpRenderer($settings['renderer']['template_path']);
    $view->setLayout('default.php');
    //$view->addAttribute('title_for_layout', $settings['title_app'] .' :: ');  
    $view->setAttributes([
      'title_for_layout'=>$settings['title_app'] .' :: ',
      'link' => $c->get('link')
    ]);  
    return $view;
};
?>


<?php
/********************/
//routes.php
/********************/


use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'your_view.php');
})->setName('home');
?>

<?php
/********************/
//your_view.php
/********************/
?>

<a href="<?=$link->pathFor('home')?>">Home</a>
```

Comment: great job! this works perfectly for me! have used $link->pathFor() prefectly; but $link->baseUrl() don't works! how to make this right way?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new class, e.g. MainMenu, and there you should create an array with all paths for menu. Object of `MainMenu` should return an array with labels and paths and then you can pass that array to your view:

```
$menu = (new MainMenu())->buildMenu();
$response = $this->view->render($response, "index.phtml", [
    'menu' => $menu
]);
```

Then in your `*.phtml` file you have access to the `$menu` variable. But what if you do not want repeat that code in each route?

Use [middlewares](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html). You can pass a variable from middleware using

```
$request = $request->withAttribute('foo', 'bar');
```

and retrieve

```
$foo = $request->getAttribute('foo');
```